# SSRS - Issue viewing all Records in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I been trying to figure out a answer to this question. Maybe its just not possible. But basically I have loaded into a table 20 Million records.

I am using SSRS to get the report and using parameters. I got one paremeter which has the selection process, so say this is userID. There is over 1000 userids. When I select all userids in the parameter the report (it is a bar graph) fails to show all the results.

But when I say select about 200-400 userids the report will show up the results with the bar graph.
The data looks clean, i just think there is a limit which is holding it back bringing everything.

Step is when I click on view report it would just click and then the screen will just remain as it is. Anyone come across any of these issues or can help thank you.

Comment: What is the value of maximum size of report? (please see details here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156002%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The size is 25.3 KB (25,968 bytes)

Comment: You don't get any errors, not even in the SSRS log or event log? Do you see the dataset query if you use SQL Profiler? Have you checked the ExecutionLog3 (or 2) views? Have you tried running the resulting query from -say- SSMS yet? Please try to check those things and edit your question and add the results as details.

Answer (score 0):

Set interval of axis from Auto to 1 (X or Y, concerned where you are showing user id).

[image]